# How to read and save base64 image format which is coming as json request in php

Tags: android, json, image, base64

I am getting user registration details from Android app in json. As part of this json i am getting profile picture as base64 format.This is the code i am using to read the json request.

```
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($request_body,true) ;
$name =  $data[0]['name'];
$email = $data[0]['email'];
$dob = $data[0]['dob'];
$pswd = $data[0]['password'];
$gender = $data[0]['gender'];
$profile_pic = $data[0]['profile_pic'];
// insert query follows
```

But when i get profile pic as part of this request i am not able to save the remaining data.Without profile pic every thing works fine. But how to save data with profile picture? I am not getting where i did mistake? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You did not make clear why you cannot handle the content of `$profile_pic`. And what do you mean with remaining data?

Comment: yes if you get data in android then only problem with fetching then you use model class and make it use of GSON plugin best way

Comment: remaining data means name, dob, gender,username etc.. able to save in db. But not profile_pic

Comment: some one can respond on this here?